# Python Password Requirement Program

Tags: python

```
def validate(s):
    global Cap, Low, Num, Spec
    ''' Checks whether the string s fits the 
        criteria for a valid password.
    ''' 
    capital =['A','B','C','D','E','F','G','H','I','J','K','L','M','N','O','P','Q','R','S','T','U','V','W','X','Y','Z']
    lowercase = ['a','b','c','d','e','f','g','h','i','j','k','l','m','n','o','p','q','r','s','t','u','v','w','x','y','z']
    number = ['0','1','2','3','4','5','6','7','8','9']
    special =['@','$','#']

    for i in s:
        if i in capital:
            Cap = True
        else: 
            Cap = False
        if s in lowercase:
            Low = True
        else:
            Low = False
        if s in number:
            Num = True
        else:
            Num = False
        if s in special:
            Spec = True
        else:
            Spec = False

    if Cap and Low and Num and Spec is True:
        return ('valid')
    else:
        return ('not valid')



def main():
    ''' The program driver. '''

    # set cmd to anything except quit()
    cmd = ''

    # process the user commands
    while  cmd != 'quit':
        cmd = input('> ')
        password = cmd 
        validate(password)


main()
```

Can someone explain to me why my program is not returning either 'not valid' or valid? This program is supposed to see if the input is a valid or invalid password based on the requirements of capital, lowercase, number and special. Thanks for the help.

Comment: Where are you calling this function? Also, please fix your indentation, as written, `validate` is a function that doesn't do anything, and you're returning from the global scope, which seems wrong.

Comment: You keep redefining everything for each letter.  Just define each variable as `False` before the loop, and in the loop remove all of the `else` blocks.  Also, in `if Cap and Low and Num...`, you don't need the `is True` at the end.

Comment: Also, the variables should presumably not be `global`, unless one word passing implies all subsequent words pass...

Comment: Just minor comment, in each three later if statement, it should be "i in" , not "s in"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Do not use global variables.  Place the `if ... else` inside the function.
2. Initialize each of the four variables to `False` before the `for` loop.  Then set them to True only when the condition is met.
3. You can shorten the lists of characters.  Either use comparisons like `if 'A' <= i <= 'Z'` or use the `str.islower()`, `str.isupper()` and `str.isdigit()`.  For the special characters, you can test if a `i` is inside a string.
4. Use `i` (and not `s` in the tests)
5. Return value does not need to be in parentheses.
6. You can use `elif` since the four categories are mutually exclusive.

Which gives

```
def validate(s):
  """ Checks whether the string s fits the 
  criteria for a valid password. Requires one of each
  of the following: lowercase, uppercase, digit and special char
  """ 
  special = '@$#'

  Cap,Low,Num,Spec = False,False,False,False
  for i in s:
    if i.isupper():
      Cap = True
    elif i.islower():
      Low = True
    elif i.isdigit():
      Num = True
    elif i in special:
      Spec = True

  if Cap and Low and Num and Spec:
    return 'valid'
  else:
    return 'not valid'
```

and verify with (assume python3, use `raw_input` for python2)

```
p = input("Password?")
print (validate(p))
```

Answer (score -1):

Your program wont return anything because you did not print anything. And your while is forever looping unless you type `quit`.

```
def main():
    cmd = ''
    while  cmd != 'quit':
        cmd = raw_input('> ')
        isValid = validate(cmd)
        print isValid
        if isValid == 'valid':
            return
```

If you are using python < 3.x use `raw_input`. And if `$ python script.py` does not work, try `$ python -i script.py`.

Hope this helps.

Comment: This doesn't perform the validation checking I'm guessing they're going for (requiring that the password contain at least one character from each of the four classes).

Comment: Ah, Im sorry missed that one, ill update. :) thanks for pointing that out.